# Return element inside a class, Python. BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup

I've created a simple class with settings to BeautifulSoup but every time I try use it (the item 'soup') he return error.

```
class Settings:

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        requests.get(url, headers={'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}, timeout=15)
        html = urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        type(soup)

    def soup_element(self):
        return(self.type(soup))

settings_website_1 = Settings('https://www.auchandirect.pl/auchan-warszawa/pl/search?text=pepsi+cola&callback=true')
print(settings_website_1.soup_element())
```

How can I reach the element correctly type(soup)? To use it in sytuation like this?

```
links = soup.findAll('a')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

```
url = "https://www.auchandirect.pl/auchan-warszawa/pl/search?text=pepsi+cola&callback=true"
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}, timeout=15)
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)
```

Comment: Do you have lxml installed?

Comment: of course, in such a situation as i added now above, all everything works good. I plan to get to the links in the middle, so creating a class would save me rewriting the code. I think that the error is due to the rare use of classes (and I make a simple error).

Comment: answered, it works with the changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't made `soup` a class member.

Try changing the following:

at the `__init__` method, change `soup` to `self.soup`

and change the `soup_element` method to:

```
def soup_element(self):
    return self.soup
```

Now, you can use:

```
WEBSITE = 'https://www.auchandirect.pl/auchan-warszawa/pl/search?' \
          'text=pepsi+cola&callback=true'
settings_website = Settings(WEBSITE)
soup_obj = settings_website.soup_element()
print soup_obj.findAll("a")
```

And get the result as a list:

```
[<a class="logo logo-auchan " href="/auchan-warszawa/pl/">\n<img alt="Zakupy spo\u017cywcze przez Internet \u2013 Zbijamy ceny   
zawodowo online \u2013 Sklep Auchandirect.pl" class=" lazyload" data-src="/images/h42/hfb/8805727109150.png" height="" src=
"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" title="Auchan.pl logo" width=""/>\n</a>, <a class="logo 
logo-mobile " href="/auchan-warszawa/pl/">\n<img alt="Zakupy spo\u017cywcze przez Internet \u2013 Zbijamy ceny zawodowo online \u2013 
Sklep Auchandirect.pl" class=" lazyload" data-src="/images/h42/hfb/8805727109150.png" height="" src=
...
```